# Laravel nested relations eager load respect ancestor id

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, eager-loading, eloquent-relationship

Let's say I have a model called `Research`. Each research belongsToMany `Location` models. And each `Location` model BelongsToMany `Contact` models. BUT, each `Contact` is also related to `Research`.

```
class Research extends Model {
   protected $table = 'researches';

   public function locations()
   {
      return BelongsToMany( Location::class, 'research_locations_list', 'research_id', 'location_id' );
   }
}

class Location extends Model {
   protected $table = 'locations';

   public function researches()
   {
      return BelongsToMany( Research::class, 'research_locations_list', 'research_id', 'location_id' );
   }

   public function contacts()
   {
      return BelongsToMany( Contact::class, 'location_contacts_list', 'location_id', 'contact_id' );
   }
}

class Contact extends Model {
   protected $table = 'contacts';

   public function locations()
   {
      return BelongsToMany( Location::class, 'location_contacts_list', 'location_id', 'contact_id' );
   }
}
```

`researches` table:

```
+----+------------+
| id |  research  |
+----+------------+
|  1 | Research 1 |
|  2 | Research 2 |
+----+------------+
```

`locations` table:

```
+----+---------------+
| id |   location    |
+----+---------------+
|  1 | United States |
|  2 | Great Britain |
|  3 | Germany       |
+----+---------------+
```

`contacts` table:

```
+----+---------+
| id | contact |
+----+---------+
|  1 | Jack    |
|  2 | John    |
|  3 | Hanz    |
+----+---------+
```

`research_locations_list` table:

```
+----+-------------+-------------+
| id | research_id | location_id |
+----+-------------+-------------+
|  1 |           1 |           1 |
|  2 |           1 |           2 |
|  3 |           2 |           2 |
|  4 |           2 |           3 |
+----+-------------+-------------+
```

So Research 1 is being conducted in United States and Great Britain, Research 2 in Great Britain and Germany

`location_contacts_list` table:

```
+----+-------------+------------+-------------+
| id | location_id | contact_id | research_id |
+----+-------------+------------+-------------+
|  1 |           1 |          1 |           1 |
|  2 |           1 |          2 |           1 |
|  3 |           2 |          1 |           2 |
|  4 |           3 |          3 |           2 |
+----+-------------+------------+-------------+
```

Research 1 should have Jack and John as contacts in United States and no contacts elsewhere;

Research 2 should have John as contact in Great Britain and Hanz in Germany;

Now, with lazy load I can achieve that:

```
$researches = Research::all();

foreach( $researches as $research )
{
    foreach( $research->locations as $location )
    {
        $contacts = $location->contacts()->wherePivot( 'research_id', $research->id )->get();
        // Will return John and Jack in United States for Research 1 and John in Great Britain and Hanz in Germany for Research 2
    }
}
```

Now, the question is: how do I achieve this with eager loading?

```
$researches = Research::with( 'locations.contacts' )->all();

foreach( $researches as $research )
{
    foreach( $research->locations as $location )
    {
        $contacts = $location->contacts;
        // Will return John and Jack in United States, John in Great Britain ( which is not supposed to happen ) for Research 1 and John in Great Britain and Hanz in Germany for Research 2
    }
}
```

Perhaps I can instruct somehow for contacts to respect ancestor id? Like:

```
$research = Research::with( 'locations.contacts' )->where( 'researches.id = location_contacts_list.research_id' )->all();
```

**UPDATE**

The closest I came up to solving this is modifying the `Location` model like this:

```
class Location extends Model {
   protected $table = 'locations';

   public function researches()
   {
      return BelongsToMany( Research::class, 'research_locations_list', 'research_id', 'location_id' );
   }

   public function contacts()
   {
      return BelongsToMany( Contact::class, 'location_contacts_list', 'location_id', 'contact_id' );
   }

   // Modify contacts attribute getter
   public function getContactsAttribute()
   {
      $contacts = $this->contacts();
      
      if( !empty( $this->pivot->research_id ) )
      {
         $contacts = $contacts->wherePivot( 'research_id', $this->pivot->research_id );
      }
      
      return $contacts->get();
   }
}
```

But it looks kind of dirty...

Answer (score 1):

In your solution you get N+1 query problem.  I can suggest the following solution:

```
class Research extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'researches';

    public function locations(): BelongsToMany
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Location::class, 'research_locations_list');
    }

    public function contacts(): BelongsToMany
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Contact::class, 'location_contacts_list')
            ->withPivot('location_id');
    }

    public function contactsByLocationAttribute(int $locationId): Collection
    {
        return $this->contacts
            ->filter(static function ($contact) use ($locationId) {
                return $contact->pivot->location_id === $locationId;
            });
    }
}


$researches = Research::with(['locations', 'contacts'])->get();
foreach ($researches as $research) {
    foreach ($research->locations as $location) {
        $contacts = $research->contactsByLocation($location->id);
    }
}
```

here there will always be only 3 queries to the database. And only necessary models will be loaded

Answer (score 0):

If I got it right, you want to add some conditions inside your `with` statement. If you want to use eloquent syntax, you can do it like this:

```
$research = Research::with(['YOUR RELATION' => function ($query) {
    $query->where('YOUR COLUMN', 'EQUALS TO SOMETHING');
}])->get();
```

Keep in mind that since inside `with` you use nested relationships, like `locations.contacts`, the `where` function inside the query, will filter only the last model (in this case that would be `contacts`). If you want to filter both locations and contacts based on some conditions, you have to write something similar to this (just an example):

```
$research = Research::with(['locations' => function ($query) {
    $query->where('id', 1)->with(['contacts' => function ($query) {
        $query->where('name', 'Tim');
    }]);
})->get();
```

In order to do that though, you need to create a relationship also with your pivot table (if you want to use it also inside the conditions). Otherwise, you have to use a different syntax, using joins. Check this page from docs for query builders https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries#main-content

Comment: The problem is that I can't have ancestor id in nested relation while eager loading because the ancestor is not yet retrieved.
`$research = Research::with(['locations' => function ($query) {
    $query->with(['contacts' => function ($query) {
        $query->where('research_id', 'ancestor_id_of_research_here');
    }]);
})->get();`

Comment: Not sure that I got it. What do you mean as 'ancestor_id_of_research'? In your example from what table would you want to retrieve that 'ancestor_id'?

Comment: `researches.id` from `Research` model

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, this https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through helps you. You should try to this